# Indy idHttp freezes - How to work with keep-alive?

Tags: delphi, sockets, delphi-2010, indy

I developed a Webserver that uses `idHttpServer` and a client application that uses `idHTTP`.

I am using Delphi 2010 and the latest indy svn source from trunk.

This application sends about 1000 requests to the Web Server in a loop. Because of `TIME_WAITS` and the overhead of connecting to a webserver, I need to use `keep-alive`. The problem is: after making about 700 requests to the server, my application (the client side) hangs for almost 10 minutes when posting data to the webserver (that happens almost every time).

So, I need to know how to properly use keep-alive with indy.

So far I have this code:

On the client side:

```
oIndyHttpClient := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
oIndyHttpClient.ProxyParams.Clear;
oIndyHttpClient.Request.CacheControl := 'no-cache';
oIndyHttpClient.ProtocolVersion := pv1_1;
oIndyHttpClient.HTTPOptions := oIndyHttpClient.HTTPOptions + [hoKeepOrigProtocol];
oIndyHttpClient.ReuseSocket := rsOSDependent;
oIndyHttpClient.Request.Connection := 'keep-alive';
```

And on the server side:

```
oIdHttpServer.OnCommandGet := Self.OnClientRead;
oIdHttpServer.AutoStartSession := False;
oIdHttpServer.KeepAlive := False;

procedure TPLKWSServerSocketIndy.OnClientRead(AContext: TIdContext; ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  //do some stuff here
  if LowerCase(ARequestInfo.Connection) = 'keep-alive' then begin
    AResponseInfo.CloseConnection := False;
  end
  else begin
    AResponseInfo.CloseConnection := True;
  end;
end;
```

Am i doing it right? What can be causing the client application do freeze and do not complete the post request?

I tried do debug the server when the client freezes, but the `OnClientRead`method does not get fired. It seems to me that the client is having issues trying to connect do the web server.

If I modify the client code to:

```
oIndyHttpClient.ProtocolVersion := pv1_0;
oIndyHttpClient.Request.Connection := 'close';
```

The client app does not freeze and everything works nice.

Should I clear `IOHandler.InputBuffer` before sending a request to the server? Is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You do not need to manage keep-alives manually on the server side.  `TIdHTTPServer` handles that for you.  Simply set the `TIdHTTPServer.KeepAlive` property to True (it is False by default, and your code is setting it to False anyway) and do not set the `AResponseInfo.CloseConnection` property at all.  TIdHTTPServer decides what value to set it to, on a per-request basis, before firing the `OnCommandGet` event.

Comment: OK, but is the client code ok? Am I doing it right? You have any idea why the request hangs? Is the request hanging because of my mistakes on the server code?

Comment: Your client code is fine (though I would remove the use of the `ReuseSocket` property). You will just have to debug TIdHTTP's internal code to find where the hanging is actually occuring.  You should also have a packet sniffer running to make sure the server is actually sending data back to the client around the time when the hang starts occuring.

Comment: I am not sure if i got this right. Does the server sends data back to the client at any time? I never saw this happening.

Comment: HTTP uses a command/response model.  By default, `TIdHTTPServer` does not send anything back to the client until the client sends a request to the server first.  Unless you send data to the client manually by accessing the connection directly, such as if you are trying to implement an HTTP server push model (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_push#HTTP_server_push).